# Unable to install SDK Platform 4.0.3

Tags: android, sdk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, platform

I'm trying to install the SDK for android 4.0.3 but I get an error and it does not download nor install.

```
Unexpected Error installing 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 2': org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
```

This is the error.
Anyone know how to fix it ? :)

EDIT:
Problem fixed, don't know why nor do I know why the problem even occured.

Comment: Try closing Eclipse and running the SDK Manager outside of Eclipse (either `SDK Manager.exe` or `tools/android` within your SDK installation).

Comment: I don't even have Eclipse installed, which is why this error is really weird. Using Windows 7.

It's downloading now, but I still don't understand why this error even came up.

Answer (score 9):

You need to run SDK Manager with Administrator Permission.

Try Run as Administrator by right-click on it

Answer (score 0):

please install "ARM EABI v7a System Image" when you install 4.0.3

Comment: Tried that, but got an error that said that the SDK Platform for 4.0.3 had to be installed, but I could not install that because of some weird error. It is working and installing now, still don't know what caused that error to appear.

Answer (score 0):

update your ADT 16.0.1 and then try..

Comment: see his comment in Question he does not have installed eclipse